# Python: interpolate.UnivariateSpline package 'error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=0'

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have been attempting to plot a line, along with a spline fitting. The following is a generalised version of my code. 'x_coord' and 'y_coord' are lists containing lists of float values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate as ipl

for a in range(len(x_coord)):
    plt.plot(x_coord[a],y_coord[a],label='Label')
    yinterp = ipl.UnivariateSpline(x_coord[a],y_coord[a],s=1e4)(x_coord[a])
    plt.plot(x_coord[a],yinterp,label='Spline Fit')
```

While I believe this has worked for me in the past, I now obtain an error message:

```
/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.pyc in __init__(self, x, y, w, bbox, k, s, ext)
    165 
    166         data = dfitpack.fpcurf0(x,y,k,w=w,
--> 167                                 xb=bbox[0],xe=bbox[1],s=s)
    168         if data[-1] == 1:
    169             # nest too small, setting to maximum bound

error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=0
```

I have seen cases of similar error messages (e.g. [dfitpack.error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222493/dfitpack-error-mk-failed-for-hidden-m-fpcurf0m-1)), only in that particular case there seemed to be problems involving dictionaries, of which none are used in my code.

Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a `UnivariateSpline` object with a zero-length array

```
    >>> from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
    >>> UnivariateSpline([], [])
    <snip>
    dfitpack.error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=0
    >>> 
    >>> UnivariateSpline([1], [2])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   <snip>
    dfitpack.error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=1
```

The error is likely triggered by [this line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/src/fitpack.pyf#L264), which sets a hidden variable `m` to the length of `x` and checks that you have at least `k+1` points where `k` is the spline degree (default is cubic, k=3).

```
>>> spl = UnivariateSpline(range(4), range(4))
>>> spl(2)
array(2.0)
```