# Cubic spline interpolation filling NaN with larger values than the following value

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am doing a cubic spline interpolation and the output I am getting seems a little odd to me. The values being inputted into the NaN values are larger than numbers prior to the NaN and larger than the value directly after the NaN. If I use `method=linear` there is no problem. However, I would much prefer to use `method=cubicspline`.

Below is an example of the section of what I wish to interpolate and what the output is:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].interpolate(method='cubicspline')
```

**before interpolate**

```
    a
1  12.036
2  12.22
3  12.306
4  17.019
5  NaN
6  NaN
7  NaN
8  18.624
9  18.615
10 19.098
11 19.156
```

**after interpolate**

```
    a
1  12.036
2  12.22
3  12.306
4  17.019
5  20.0825
6  20.5013
7  19.5803
8  18.624
9  18.615
10 19.098
11 19.156
```

If anyone knows if I am doing something wrong I would really appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you plotting this to convince yourself that the interpolation is actually producing something sensible there. If you want that not to happen just do not interpolate the nan and use whatever prior knowledge you feel appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a full picture of why is this happening, you have to plot the spline in much finer steps to reveal the cubic polynomial that have been fit.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [12.036, 12.22, 12.306, 17.019, 18.624, 18.615, 19.098, 19.15]
ipoints = [12.036, 12.22, 12.306, 17.019, 20.0825, 20.5013, 19.5803, 18.624, 18.615, 19.098, 19.15]

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11], points, label='real')
plt.plot(range(1, 12), ipoints, label='pandas')

from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline as CS

cs = CS([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11], points)
plt.plot(range(1, 12), cs(range(1, 12)), label='scipy')

x = np.linspace(1, 12, 200)
plt.plot(x, cs(x), label='scipy-fine')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks.  Have you ever had a go at using spline interpolation using groupby?
I have columns desired in col.I try the following:
df[col] = df.groupby('id')[col].apply(lambda x : x.interpolate(method='spline',order=3))
But get this error `error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=1` Any idea?

Comment: No, I haven't had to use it in such a way. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230362/python-interpolate-univariatespline-package-error-mk-failed-for-hidden-m) answer will help you