# Catch dfitpack.error from scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, scipy, interpolation

I am interpolating an array and there is the possibility, that I might not have enough knots for the interpolation. In this case, I will need to adjust the degree of the smoothing spline. In the minimal working example given below, this would be the case if `N = 3`.

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
import numpy as np

N = 10       # is working fine
# N = 3      # produces error
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, N)
y = np.exp(-x**2) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(N)
spline = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, bbox=[x[0],x[-1]], k=3, ext=0)

x_full = np.linspace(-3,3,10*N)
yspline = spline(x_full)
```

The error, if `N=3` is
 `error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=3`.
The same error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230362/python-interpolate-univariatespline-package-error-mk-failed-for-hidden-m) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222493/dfitpack-error-mk-failed-for-hidden-m-fpcurf0m-1). I know what this error means and know why it appears, this is not the issue.

I would like to write a try/except to catch this case and handle it appropriately.
What `<ErrorType>` would this be?

```
try:
    spline = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, bbox=[x[0],x[-1]], k=3, ext=0)
    yspline = spline(x_full)
except <ErrorType>:
    print('something')
```

(I know I could instead write an `if/else` statement checking the length of `x` and `y`. I will keep this in mind as an alternative. But for know, it would be better to use the `try/except` statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except Exception` . While generally considered bad form (for a reason!), it'll work here.